How useful are geometrical concepts and structures in Non-Equilibrium Thermodynamics?
There are quite a few questions (1, 2, 3) on Physics SE about the geometrical structure of thermodynamics. I am really intrigued by this approach, but it feels to me that in equilibrium thermodynamics, it is overkill (meaning that, usually, it is not strictly necessary to use it; it is just a really elegant way to rephrase results).
Given that, I wonder: is there a well-established and useful application of contact geometry (or symplectic geometry on Riemannian manifolds, as suggested in some works) to non-equilibrium thermodynamics? By "useful and well-established," I mean an application that has been shown to predict or explain, in a clear and unambiguous way, non-equilibrium phenomena in real systems—phenomena that would otherwise be more easily approached using more conventional methods, such as Prigogine's Local Equilibrium Hypothesis or similar approaches.
This question has been also proposed in Physics SE due to the broad range of scientific implications that, in my opinion, it has. I would love to get some insight also from more chemistry-oriented people like me.

"given that in equilibrium thermodynamics it seems like overkill" I don't get this. Development of non-eq thermo introduced ideas beyond equilibrium thermo. Your question is whether the geometrical description of equilibrium thermo is useful to understand non-equilibrium thermo? Of course, some abstract mathematical considerations may be ignored, but fundamental aspects of a theory cannot be entirely disregarded. One starts consideration of non-eq thermo looking at small time perturbations of equilibrium states (differential calculus).

I did not find the duplicate at phys SE. Please provide a link and avoid duplication. This question seems more appropriate at phys SE so you might close it here if you get an answer there.

Well, I was specifically talking of Differential Geometry concepts and the use of Contact Structures in Thermodynamics. For equilibrium processes, such description is hardly more useful than the classic one based on convex functions and the notion of differentials. Obviously the underlying theory should be the same but I was looking at examples in which the geometrical formulation (that is, in my reasoning, the use of contact structures and exterior derivatives) is fundamental to explain a non equilibrium phenomenon clearly and concisely.

I am aware of the usual application of differential calculus in non-eq thermodynamics, which essentially borrows most of its formalism from continuum mechanics, I was just wondering if there are examples of works which would not be possible by just using those kind of reasonings but instead become approachable using the aforementioned geometric structures.

I also added the link to the SE question

Also, I hate to duplicate posts, but in this particular case, I felt there was a slight chance that some folks in the Chemistry SE had the expertise to answer and, at the same time, were not active in Physics SE. As soon as I obtain an answer (if it happens), I will delete the question here (or vice versa).

(For context, I have published work on NET.) I agree the geometric formalism is overkill in ET, and honestly it's too formal to have been of much use to me in NET as well. As far as geometry goes, you might be interested in ideas like the Wasserstein metric as used in optimal transport and maybe information theory, and of course there's the standard Gaussian field theories of fluctuating hydrodynamics, etc.

Thank god, that's a nice perspective on the matter, I will leave things open but I hope more comments from guys like you keep coming

@a-cyclohexane-molecule I will certainly read about Wasserstein metric and tbh I will also keep on looking on geometric formalisms only because I love abstract math but it is reassuring to hear something from guys publishing in the field.
